# Rails has_one not saving foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following tables

```
keyword
  keyword_id - PK
  description
  status_id - FK

keyword_status
  status_id - PK
  description
```

Trying to model them in AR and when attempting to save in my test it's not saving the status ID in keyword.  They are mapped as such:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :keyword
  self.primary_key = :KEYWORD_ID  

  attr_writer :description
  attr_writer :keyword_status

  has_one :keyword_status, foreign_key: :STATUS_ID

end

class KeywordStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :keyword_status
  self.primary_key = :STATUS_ID
end
```

and the code where it breaks (keyword status is populated by a fixture)

```
keyword = Keyword.new
keyword.description = "keyword#{n}"
keyword.keyword_status = KeywordStatus.first
keyword.save
```

When `keyword.save` is called i get cannot insert NULL into 'STATUS_ID' on table Keyword

NOTE: I cannot change any of the DDL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dstarh said, the foreign key association is backwards. In your models you should only need:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :keyword_status
end

class KeywordStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword, :foreign_key => "status_id"
end
```

For the association to work. Also, setting the `KeywordStatus` object up with a fixture before creating the associated object is a bit odd but will work if that is the behavior you need. Also, why not just use the foreign key `keyword_id` and let rails handle it for you?

Update if you want to use `keyword_id` instead of `status_id` as the foreign key:

the tables will be as such:

```
keyword
 id - PK
 description

keyword_status
 id - PK
 keyword_id - FK
 description
```

And your models:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :keyword_status
end

class KeywordStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword
end
```

Hope this helps!

Update 2: Given the tables cannot change the association has to be a bit backwards. I would recommend:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword_status
end

class KeywordStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :keywords, :foreign_key => "status_id" 
end
```

I used a has many as the association since from what has been said it looks like a keyword can share a status that another keyword has. This also means that you will have to do something like:

```
KeywordStatus.first.keywords = KeywordStatus.first.keywords.push(keyword)
KeywordStatus.save
```

instead of:

```
keyword.keyword_status = KeywordStatus.first
```

Which operates in the opposite direction than you want. As you can see this can get pretty confusing so if at all possible i would suggest writing a migration to change your tables (this can be done for tables that have existing data if that is the problem). Again I hope this helps!

Comment: the fixtures are there because there are only ever 3 statuses, active, disabled and new.  There will be thousands of keywords most of which will be active with a few disabled & new

Comment: This still has the same effect but now get deprication warnings trying to create attribute keyword_id.

Comment: Did you updated your migration replacing `status_id` with `keyword_id`? Also this is just a suggestion, so if you want to stick with using `status_id` as your foreign key you certainly can. Also, for your fixtures the only reason it is odd is because the primary object is usually created before the associated object but from what you say this looks to not be the case so what you are doing for that is fine. I will update the answer with what your tables should look like should you want to change the foreign key.

Comment: I updated my question to say that I cannot change the tables - they are all pre-existing.

Comment: The foreign key is supposed to be placed on the `belongs_to` part of the association so not changing the tables is a bit of complication, this just means that the association is backwards, `KeywordStatus` is now the parent object and the `Keyword` is the associated object. I will update my answer above.

Comment: the keyword_status would not have a keyword_id as there are only ever to be 3 keyword_statuses, the keyword has a status

Answer (score 2):

You got the direction wrong. It should be keyword belongs_to status. The general rule is that the model that has the foreign key column belongs to the other model.

Comment: i figured it would be something simple like this, it just seems backwards to me.  This I'm assuming lets you find all of the keywords with a given status?  Assuming I setup the has_many on the status side?

Comment: unfortunately that didn't seem to make any difference